# Adding detail to highly-upvoted answer at a later date

Tags: discussion

I rolled the dice and answered this (not-super-great) question relating to CO<sub>2</sub> emissions, and my answer is now sitting at +131:

> [Have China and India more than doubled carbon emissions since 2000 while U.S. emissions have fallen?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/45799/38403)

It hit the HNQ list, and as a result generated lots of comments, which have gone through a few rounds of clean-up (thanks @Oddthinking for the vigilance there!).

However, a consistent theme has arisen in the comments, encapsulated by [this one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45799/have-china-and-india-more-than-doubled-carbon-emissions-since-2000-while-u-s-em/45800#comment212895_45800), currently at +80:

> If a person in the US buys something made in china [*sic*], which line on the chart gets bumped up, if any?

I found a good resource (see this page from Our World in Data on [consumption-based CO<sub>2</sub> emissions](https://ourworldindata.org/consumption-based-co2)) to address these comments, but I'm reluctant to edit the question at this point for a few reasons:

- Consumption-based emissions is relevant to the topic, but not really addressed by the question or the claim it asks about
- Lots of people voted on the answer "as-is." Does adding this significant piece of info invalidate their votes?

I poked around on [metase], but didn't find anything addressing this concern.

Comment: Especially HNQ votes are practically worthless, if not a wholesale negative impact. It's *your* answer. If you think addressing this is valuable, then do it (I guess it's *relevant* as well). [At this point it is properly spelled "metastase".;( ]

Answer (score 1):

Given that there was a highly-upvoted comment (+89, when I saw it, +92 now) asking for that angle, I think it was fairly appropriate.

And since the (rather unclear) question also involved on what Thunberg thought of that... *and* it turns out (see my answer) that she thought that was a relevant angle too...

> *Is China responsible for a lot of the greenhouse emissions in the world?*
>
> Every country is responsible in some part, but there are a lot of factories in China and they manufacture a lot of the stuff that the western world buys.

I think it was doubly appropriate to add that info, even though you never mentioned Thunberg in your answer.